# How Can I compare a Column in a Self Join with itself if it is Not Null?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, nvl

I'm doing an update to a temp table in Oracle. My thinking was that I could use NVL to set a value ( essentially making the null value on either side equal )

What happens in the update is that if a number of comparisons hold true then a column is not updated, one of those compared columns can be null and Oracle does not compare null values.

The Code may make it easier to understand.

```
UPDATE Temp_Table A Set T.ColZ = 'something'
WHERE NOT EXISTS
( SELECT * FROM Temp_Table B
WHERE A.ColF = B.ColF
AND ...more column comparisons
AND ((NVL(A.ColC, 'N/A') = NVL(B.ColC, 'N/A'))
     AND more column Comparisons)
);
```

The update works when ColC contains no Nulls but when I have a row that ColC is Null then it gets updated despite being the same on both sides.

I had also tried using a subquery in the where clause but with no luck. Would a subquery be a better method to use here?

Any help or hints are greatly appreciated.

Just wanted to add that ideally I would like to skip the comparison altogether if that col is null so any ideass on how to do it that way are welcome.
Thanks

A per Ypers request an example with a few rows... hopefully it is clear enough

```
Temp_Table
Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |Col5 |Col6
AB   |  DC  |  EF  |  GH  | 08  |
BA   |  CD  |  EF  |  GH  | 08  |
AB   |  DC  |  HI  |  NULL| 05  |
AB   |  DC  |  JK  |  LM  | 04  |
```

In the above table row 1 matches with row 2. My update is supposed to single out rows like 3 and 4 where there is no corresponding row. I can get it to work when Col4 is not Null but it fails when that value is Null. Just FYi in the temp_table any Col2 that has DC  value Col1 will have AB as its value and the for any CD value in Col2 then Col1 has BA as its value.

```
UPDATE Temp_Table T SET Col6 = 'Unmatched'
WHERE NOT EXISTS
( SELECT * FROM Temp_Table B
 WHERE T.Col3 = B.Col3
 AND   T.COl4 = B.Col4
 AND   T.COl5 = B.Col5 )
```

Hope that helps and thanks.

Comment: Why changing that into `(A.ColC = B.ColC)` doesn't work?

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with what you've posted; the problem is probably elsewhere. Can you post a small, complete `temp_table` and a small, complete `UPDATE` statement that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @ypercube: Note the `WHERE NOT EXISTS`. The point is that the subquery *should* find records in `Temp_Table B` matching the records in `Temp_Table A` even if that field is `NULL`, but the OP believes that it doesn't work.

Comment: Updated the main post as per Ypers and Ruaks requests for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to change:

```
((NVL(A.ColC, 'N/A') = NVL(B.ColC, 'N/A'))
```

to:

```
(A.ColC = B.ColC OR A.ColC IS NULL OR B.ColC IS NULL)
```

---

After the question's update.

You could try this:

```
UPDATE Temp_Table T 
SET Col6 = 'Unmatched'
WHERE NOT EXISTS
( SELECT * 
  FROM Temp_Table B
  WHERE T.Col3 = B.Col3
    AND T.COl4 = B.Col4
    AND T.COl5 = B.Col5

    AND NOT (  T.Col1 = B.Col1    --- all the other columns except Col6
           AND T.Col2 = B.Col2
            )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately, I can't seem to make this work the way that it needs to. Ruakh is correct btw when i he says that where these matches don't exist is where the update happens. Not sure if that helps clear things up or not. I'll keep working on it. Thanks.

Comment: @dee: If you can locate the issue to an example with a few rows, it would help us understand what the issue is exactly.

Comment: I made a small temp_table example in my post... not sure if it helps to clarify. Thanks

Comment: @dee: OK, I think I understand now. Does the table have a Primary or Unique Key?

Comment: No it has no pk or fk ... it's a temp table in a stored proc, if I'm not mistaken, temp tables in oracle do automatically have a rowid however. not sure if we can link them up that way or not. I'm currently working a with a merge statement to see if that works better.

Comment: tried it and it works although I switched essentially to a merge statement so no I'm updating when it matches to one thing and when it does not match to something else. Thanks for all your help and insight.